# How can I use CMake to install a script?

Tags: cmake, installation, deb, cpack

I have a project that builds several executables and also installs them.  For the executables the relevant CMake code is:

```
add_executable(foo "foo.cpp")
add_executable(bar "bar.cpp;qux.cpp")
install(TARGETS foo bar "/usr/bin")
```

Then I create a .deb package and when it installs I can run `foo` and `bar` from the command line.  I want to do something like this:

```
add_executable(foo "foo.cpp")
add_executable(bar "bar.cpp;qux.cpp")
add_script(hello "hello.sh")
install(TARGETS foo bar hello)
```

...so that `hello` is executable from the command line.  But there isn't actually a CMake command called `add_script`.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use

```
install(PROGRAMS hello.sh DESTINATION bin RENAME hello)
```

which will automatically make your script executable.  See [the docs for install(FILES)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-files):

> The PROGRAMS form is identical to the FILES form except that the default permissions 
>   for the installed file also include OWNER_EXECUTE, GROUP_EXECUTE, and WORLD_EXECUTE. 
>   This form is intended to install programs that are not targets, such as shell scripts.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it would be simple, it just turned out to be hard to search for:

```
install(FILES "hello.sh"
    PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE OWNER_EXECUTE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE
    DESTINATION "bin"
    RENAME "hello")
```